# Python Selenium special char - write file

Tags: python, selenium, stream, special-characters

I am testing Selenium with Python, but I have problems with special chars.

I tried to add the following at the begining of script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But it does not change anything, I get "?" that replace special char. I don't know how to do.

If I make a print like as follow, it works fine :

```
print("Café")
```

But if I write in a file, it does not work. So Here is my script :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://openclassrooms.com/fr/")

html = driver.page_source

import os
helloFile = open('C:\\Users\\Myaccount\\Desktop\\page.html', 'w')
helloFile.write(html)
helloFile.close()

driver.close()
```

And the result : 
[image]

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same script on my machine, just am using `chrome driver` and not `firefox driver`, its work normally

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
prefs = {'profile.managed_default_content_settings.images': 2, "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2 }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver= webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://openclassrooms.com/fr/")
html = driver.page_source

import os
helloFile = open('page.html', 'w')
helloFile.write(html)
helloFile.close()
driver.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks, the problem comes from the display of my firefox config, I think